# sqlalchemy column named user, inconsistency

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am intefacing a postgresql database via sqlalchemy (python).
In there I have a talbe like this:

```
SELECT * from mytable;

 id | user | password |      host       | port 
----+------+----------+-----------------+------
  1 | abc  | def      |    127.0.0.1    |   21
```

But now if I try to do a equivalent (I thought ...) select from out of my code like so:

```
s = sql.select(columns=['user', 'password', ...]).select_from('mytable')
```

Instead of the entries from the user column (abc), I get name of the the database user.

Also I noticed that the psql client renames the user field to 'current_user', if the column names are explicitly specified in the select statement:

```
SELECT user, password, host, port FROM mytable;

 current_user | password |      host       | port 
--------------+----------+-----------------+------
 abc          | def      |    127.0.0.1    |   21
```

Do I have to rename all my table columns, in order to avoid the mixups?
Or does sqlalchemy provide a solution for this problem?

Here is the table spec:

```
\dS mytable;
                                Table "public.mytable"
  Column  |            Type             |                            Modifiers                             
----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
 id       | integer                     | not null default nextval('mytable_id_seq'::regclass)
 user     | character varying           | not null
 password | character varying           | not null
 host     | character varying           | not null
 port     | integer                     | not null

Indexes:
    "mytable_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common mistake.

`user` is an alias for [`current_user`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html), the keyword for an SQL standard pseudo function.

Use `"user"` (i.e. double-quote the identifier) if you want a table or column of that name. Or choose your table/column names not to conflict with [reserved keywords](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

ORMs and query generators should be automatically double quoting all keywords (or all identifiers, since there's no harm in it). Most don't, unfortunately.